# Why my css of frosted glass effect doesn't work?

Tags: css, frontend, effects

I created a demo page to try out the newly introduced `backdrop-filter` property. However I cannot see any blurring.

I was using Chrome 58 with **#enable-experimental-web-platform-features** flag turned on and **I have seen the frosted glass effect in other people's works**, including the official demo on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#Result)

Here is my code.

```css
/* Helper */
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.--frosted-glass {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);          /* Google Chrome */
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);  /* Safari for macOS & iOS*/
}

@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(10px))) {
  .--frosted-glass {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
}

.promotions {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.promotion-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 297px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.promotion-img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  transition: transform 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
}

.promotion-airline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.promotion-airline::before {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.promotion-airline>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}


/* Hover */
.promotion-box:hover>.promotion-img,
.promotion-box:focus>.promotion-img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<ul class="promotions">
  <li class="promotion-box">
    <img class="promotion-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia//commons/thumb/b/bb/Sydney_Harbour_welcomes_Jessica_Watson.jpg/400px-Sydney_Harbour_welcomes_Jessica_Watson.jpg">
    <div class="promotion-airline --frosted-glass">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/02/Qantas_Airways_logo_2016.svg/156px-Qantas_Airways_logo_2016.svg.png" alt="By Cathay Pacific">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/qiansen1386/pen/oWmMrw

> Thanks for anyone who pointed out that Chrome haven't support this feature yet, I know.. However there is a way to enable it by turning on **enable-experimental-web-platform-features** flag. See [caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter). What I want to know is, whether it is because my code haves defects or chrome's implementation have defects. Is there any css collision which have yet to be mentioned by MDN?

Comment: You can use `filter` css for blur effect ?

Comment: I posted an example with `filter` you can check

Comment: Which link you share (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#Result) is clearly mention that chrome and firefox is not supported.

Comment: It doesn't work on Chrome or Firefox. It only works in Safari 9 and iOS 9 and above.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1; 
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  filter:blur(15px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(15px);
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```